# How do I select floating-point infinity literals from a SQLite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, floating-point, infinity

I have a SQLite database with a table named `measurements`, which contains some experimental data measured by a power meter. They're stored as data type `REAL` in a field named `power_dbm`. In some measurements, the readings can be off the scale, the meter cannot obtain a reading due to overrange or underrange, thus the values `+Inf` and `-Inf` are used to represent these values.

For example, here is some of the data.

```
sqlite> SELECT power_dbm, typeof(power_dbm) from measurements;
-10.312|real
-9.908|real
-11.344|real
-Inf|real
```

As you see, there's a floating-point number of negative infinity. Unfortunate I don't know the correct syntax to select these values from the database. I tried:

```
sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm from measurements WHERE power_dbm=-Inf;
Error: no such column: Inf

sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm from measurements WHERE power_dbm='-Inf'
(nothing returned)

sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm from measurements WHERE power_dbm='-infinity';
(nothing returned)

sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm from measurements WHERE power_dbm=-1/0;
(nothing returned)

sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm from measurements WHERE power_dbm is -1/0;
(incorrect results returned, power_dbm is null instead of negative infinity)
```

What is the correct syntax to specify the literal value of positive or negative infinity in SQL/SQLite? Any additional references to relevant documentation will also greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what value is inside of column where it says -Inf|real ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Use an impossibly-huge floating-point literal

I found writing an impossibly-huge floating-point literal such as `9e999` is one way to construct `+Inf`/`-Inf`.

```
sqlite> SELECT 9e999;
Inf

sqlite> SELECT -9e999;
-Inf

sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm, typeof(power_dbm) FROM measurements
   ...> WHERE power_dbm=-9e999;
370000000|-Inf|real
440000000|-Inf|real
510000000|-Inf|real
580000000|-Inf|real
```

#### Solution 2: Use `ieee754()` with hardcoded exponent/significand for Infinity

You can construct `+Inf` and `-Inf` manually from an exponent and significand in the IEEE 754 representation via function `ieee754()`. This is the original solution I used before I found the `9e999` trick...

```
sqlite> SELECT ieee754(4503599627370496, 972);
Inf

sqlite> SELECT ieee754(-4503599627370496, 972);
-Inf

sqlite> SELECT freq_hz, power_dbm, typeof(power_dbm) FROM measurements
   ...> WHERE power_dbm=ieee754(-4503599627370496, 972);
370000000|-Inf|real
440000000|-Inf|real
510000000|-Inf|real
580000000|-Inf|real
```

The detailed usage of `ieee754()` and other related functions is documented in [Floating Point Numbers](https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html).

#### Solution 3: Use Parameterized SQL queries

Using `ieee754(-4503599627370496, 972)` feels like a more rigorous construction than a random value like `9e999`, but `9e999` is adequate for typing commands in a console by hand when all you want is having a quick look of the data, so correctness is not a real concern.

In an actual program, one would be using parameterized SQL queries instead of handling strings anyway, simply passing the native `Infinity` constant (e.g. Python's `math.inf`) in your programming language is sufficient.

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 19 2021, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> import sqlite3
>>> DB_FILE = "./data.db"
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute(
...     "SELECT power_dbm from measurements "
...     "WHERE power_dbm=?", (-math.inf,)).fetchall()
[(-inf,), (-inf,), (-inf,), (-inf,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

casting works for me:

```
SELECT power_dbm from measurements WHERE CAST(power_dbm AS CHARACTER) ='Inf';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Ah thanks. I just started using SQL and totally didn't know you can cast from string to float.